# How to cause a section of code to timeout in Java if it doesn't return with a certain timelimit?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have the following code which connects to a server, sends a request, then returns the response.

The problem is that if the client can't connect to the server, the program never progresses past this section

```
PayLoad payLoadFromServer = client.sendRequest();
```

I am just wondering what the best approach is to prevent the program from freezing, i.e. I want to timeout after say 5 seconds if the client can't connect, and be able to handle that gracefully in the program. Note I can't edit the Client class.

```
public PayLoad queryServer() {
        try (final Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1", "8080")) {
            PayLoad payLoadFromServer = client.sendRequest();

            return payLoadFromServer;
        }
    }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What is Client? Can't you propose a constructor with a timeout?

Comment: @Rory I assume that inside the Client Constructor you are initializing /starting the connection? Can you make changes to the Client?

Comment: Nope, can't edit the Client class unfortunately.

Comment: what's the underlying protocol? ie, when you say it can't connect, what kind of connection to you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to give it a very quick try. Create a wrapper object for your client class and make this new object runnable.

```
public class ClientWrapper implements Runnable {

  private final String ip;
  private final String port;
  private Client client;
  Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of ClientWrapper.
   * 
   * @param ip
   * @param port
   */
  public ClientWrapper(String ip, String port) {

    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;
  }

  public Lock getLock() {

    return lock;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void run() {

    lock.lock();
    client = new Client(ip, port);
    lock.unlock();
  }

  //create a method to expose client or its methods. 


}
```

Now use an instance of this object as a thread like below.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * @author rbhatt
 */
public class ClientCaller {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    ClientWrapper clientWrapper = new ClientWrapper("127.0.0.1", "8080");

    Thread t = new Thread(clientWrapper);
    t.start();

    boolean ret = clientWrapper.getLock().tryLock(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    if (ret == false) {
      System.out.println("can not acquire lock in 250 milliseconds, kill the thread.");
      t.interrupt();
    } else {
      System.out.println("acquired lock in 250 milliseconds,release lock obtain client!");
      clientWrapper.getLock().unlock();
    }

  }

}
```

as you can see, you can control your timeout in the caller, and we fail to obtain a lock, kill the client wrapper thread. I have used interrupt, you can use a `volatile` variable. You can also use a `executor service` and `thread pools` etc.

**Note: i have written this code just as an illustration about the idea, one can improve the code in many different ways.**

Comment: This will only work if the Client's constructor deals with interruption. If not this will not do anything.

Comment: @assylias as i have said, this just an illustration. One can improve. Instead of an interrupt one can go ahead and use, say, BlockingQueues to provide communication.

Comment: I'm just saying that in the end the answer to the question depends on how Client is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the method [connect(SocketAddress endpoint, int timeout)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29) of [java.net.Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) inside your `Client` class. It is the best solution, but it may exist others.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a timer to the Client code such that the Socket is closed if the connection is not established within 5 seconds.  This is *much harder* to do externally.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a Socket to connect to the client, you could supply a SocketFactory and set the timout for each Socket it creates.

Other wise, I would probably use two Threads. The first to do te actual connection, the second to trigger an interrupt on the first after the timeout.

This would require a series of locks, one to prevent the timeout occuring before you try and connect and one to wait on te attempt

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use Timer and here is a good link for time out for network operations.
[Handling network timeouts in Java](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/network_timeouts/)
  http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/network_timeouts/

Answer (score 0):

Not the best idea, but it depends on your's project logic and environment. You can wrap your method with ExecutorService:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

private int threads = 10;

// overide thread count to prevent too many threads to be created
private ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, threads,
        60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());

// if TimeOutException isthrown - then 5 secs is out
public PayLoad sendRequest(long timeout) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
       return executor.submit(new Callable<PayLoad>() {
            @Override
            public PayLoad call() {
                  // your code implementation of client.sendRequest();
            }
        }).get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
```

I used here cached thread pool with 10 threads. The only bad thing is wrapping each call of method with another thread. And don't forget to shutdown your pool implementation.